# Finding the functions changed in a tfs changeset

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops

Using the below code I am able to get the files changed in a changeset.
I am using the DLL "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi"

```
 var url = "https://tfs_link/tfs/project_name";
 var credentials = new VssCredentials(new WindowsCredential());
 var tfs = new TfvcHttpClient(new Uri(url), credentials);
 var changesetChanges = tfs.GetChangesetChangesAsync(12345);
 var changesetChangesResult = changesetChanges.Result;
 var array = changesetChangesResult.ToArray();
 foreach (var i in array)
 {
    var item = i.Item;
    var URL = item.Url;
    var path = item.Path;
 }
```

Is there any way where I can get the functions that are edited within the files?

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way where I can get the functions that are edited within
>   the files?

I am afraid that this is currently impossible to achieve, through the API we can get which files are modified in a changeset , but we can not get the specific content of these files modified. As far as I know, we can only find out which functions are changed by viewing the changeset in the UI.

In addition, you could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) site , which is our main forum for product suggestions. After suggest raised, you can vote and add your comments for this feedback. The product team would provide the updates if they view it.